# Incorrect syntax near '= '. in code c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm developing a c# windows form application program that saves the info about the student like name course year and etc. My code in saving to sql database works but when it comes to retreiving the info i get these error incorrect syntax near '='. i think the error is in the retreive code.please help :)

Here is the retrieve code:

```
try
{
    string sql = "SELECT studnum,course,f_name,l_name,color_image FROM table3 WHERE f_name=" + textBoxfname.Text + "";
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        labeloutputstudnum.Text = reader[0].ToString();
        labeloutputcourse.Text = reader[1].ToString();
        labeloutputfname.Text = reader[2].ToString();
        labeloutputlname.Text = reader[3].ToString();
        byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[4]);
        if (img == null)
            pictureBox3.Image = null;
        else
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
            pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        textBoxstudno.Text = "";
        textBoxcourse.Text = "";
        textBoxfname.Text = "";
        textBoxlname.Text = "";
        pictureBox3.Image = null;
        MessageBox.Show("does not exist");
    }
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: i dont know but the warning sign is in the string sql

Comment: P.S.: You make SQL injection.

Comment: [SQL INJECTION ALERT!!!! WARNING!!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: change your sql to use Parameters

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: See [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements). You want to use parameters for variable input AND use the `using` statements to ensure that connections are cleaned up when you are done.

Comment: please have al okk at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not seeing why this should be closed. It doesn't appear to be off topic. OP isn't aware of the SQL Injection vulnerability, yes, but I don't see that as grounds for closing.

Comment: @Justin: It's a simple typographical mistake, not useful to others. So, yes, it should be closed.

Comment: @JustinSelf - because SQL injection issues aside, it's just a simple invalid syntax from not quoting the string in SQL,  which has been asked before and something the OP should have researched on their own.

Comment: @sstan I understand what you are saying, but if I were in OP's shoes and my question was closed because others knew that it was a simple typo error but wouldn't tell me, I'd be pretty disheartened. However, if this is the accepted view point of the community, then it should be closed.

Comment: @Justin: That's why most of us will kindly (I hope) let OP know what the typo is in the comments, but will then vote to close the question, as it won't be of much use to other users in the community.  Because the whole point of these Q&A is to help other people down the road. At least, I'm pretty sure that was what SO was supposed to be at some point.

Comment: thanks for the response guys this is my first time asking question here in stackoverflow and i dont have some knowledge on sql infact i just copy the retreive code in some tutorial that i watch i thought it will work because the save code works. again thanks for all the response and all the advise that i get from y'all

Answer (score 5):

```
string sql = "SELECT studnum,course,f_name,l_name,color_image FROM table3 WHERE f_name=@Name";
command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", textBoxfname.Text));
```

Comment: Looks like you'll benefit from everyone's anger at the other answers.  But really, the question should simply be closed by now. The question itself is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple errors:

1. The most obvious, always use parameters in your sql statements.
2. Always use using blocks to clean up connections.
3. Do not reuse connections, this is bad practice as sql server will automatically (by default unless you turn it off exclititly) use connection pooling.

   // DO NOT reuse connections, create a new one when needed!
   using(var conn = new SqlConnection(/*use a connection from the web/app .config*/))
   {
       const string sql = "SELECT studnum,course,f_name,l_name,color_image FROM table3 WHERE f_name = @name";

   ```
   command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = textBoxfname.Text});

   conn.Open();

   /* rest of code unchanged but do not call conn.Close(), the using block will do this for you
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question, your sql query has incorrect syntax. I would break point on the sql string to see exactly what's wrong. It should be obvious when you do that.

The REAL problem though is that you're exposing your application to SQL injection. Let's look at a basic example of what you have.

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ='" + userinput.Text + "'";
```

So the user inputs some value and it gets dumped in there for the query. Simple right?

What happens if the user inputs this

```
' OR 1=1; --
```

Well let's see what your sql string turns into when that's added

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '' OR 1=1; -- '
```

So now, your query string says select the id OR where 1=1 which means where true, which means everything.

SQL injection is a real threat and the only way to stop it is to implement counter measures right from the start.

Please look into parameterization. It's very easy in C#.

[MSDN Article on C# Parameterization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score -3):

You have to use single quotes for string parameters/fields in SQL:

```
string sql = "SELECT studnum,course,f_name,l_name,color_image FROM table3 WHERE f_name='" + textBoxfname.Text + "'";
```

But it is better (more secure) to use parameters:

```
string sql = "SELECT studnum,course,f_name,l_name,color_image FROM table3 WHERE f_name=@name";
if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    conn.Open();
var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxfname.Text;
```

Comment: Do not propagate the use of SQL with SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: It is not just "better" to use parameters - it is the only correct way anyone should ever write code.  Concatenation is just wrong, wrong, wrong - this can't be said forcefully enough.

Comment: @J...: Well, as with anything, there are exceptions to the rule.  There *are* valid cases to concatenate strings into SQL statements.  But this case very much is not one of them.

Comment: You should not allow sql injection, but just (only) showing a proper design for sql queries does not help him to understand the original error message.